# Como converter o tipo de dado de uma coluna em um data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, tenho uma dúvida, como fazer a conversão de tipos de dados em uma coluna de um Data Frame ?
Tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'Estado':['SP','MG','PR','PB'],
                'Valores':['1500,35','4500,66','17500,00','5000,45']}) ; d
```

A princípio eu tentei o seguinte:

```
d['Valores'].astype(float)
```

e tive esse erro:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1500,35'
```

Então pensei, ok vamos fazer isso:

```
d['Valores'].aplly(lambda x: str(x).replace(',','.'))
```

e esse foi meu resultado:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'aplly'
```

Como proceder ? Gostaria de converter os valores que a princípio são `strings` em valores do tipo `float` !

Comment: O seu erro neste caso foi de digitação, você escreveu aplly e na verdade teria que ser apply. Conforme respondido pelo Paulo Marques, prefira funções vetorizadas quando possível ao invés de utilizar o apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consigo imaginar duas maneiras.

### Alterar o tipo na origem

Os dados já podem vir no formato correto antes de serem inseridos no dataframe. Por exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'Estado':['SP','MG','PR','PB'],
                'Valores':[1500.35, 4500.66, 17500.00, 5000.45]})
```

### Substituir vírgula por ponto e usar uma função de conversão

`d['Valores'] = d['Valores'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)`

ou

`d["Valores"] = pd.to_numeric(d["Valores"].str.replace(",", "."))`

[`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) é mais geral pois permite a conversão para outros tipos não numéricos, porém [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) pode receber o argumento `"coerce"` no parâmetro `errors`, permitindo um controle melhor de valores inválidos.

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 6):

Evite usar `apply` quando possível e aposte nas funções vetorizadas.

Para fazer o `replace` e a conversão para `float`, use:

```
d = d.assign(Valores = d['Valores'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float))
```

Comment: `fillna()` não é necessário.

Comment: @sourcream. Você tem razão, obrigado pela observação. Retirado da resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante !